# Getting org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied error only in VScode integrated terminal - connecting ZSH with spotify

Tags: dbus, zsh, spotify, visual-studio-code, mpris

I've edited powerlevel10k ZSH theme to show songs currently played by Spotify in terminal window - works perfectly, except of VS code integrated terminal. Both Spotify and VS code are installed via Snap.

My script function extending ZSH theme (I don't believe the code is wrong, because it works perfectly outside VS code):

```
  function prompt_my_spotifyplayed() {
    if test "$(pidof spotify | wc -l)" = 1; then
      artist="$(dbus-send --print-reply --session --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get string:'org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player' string:'Metadata' | awk '/artist/{getline; getline; print}' | sed 's/string//' | sed 's/"//g' | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' )"
      title="$(dbus-send --print-reply --session --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get string:'org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player' string:'Metadata' | awk '/title/{getline; print}' | sed 's/string//' | sed 's/variant//' | sed 's/"//g' | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' )"
      p10k segment -i '' -f '#1DB954' -t "${artist} - ${title}"
    fi
  }
```

Whole .zsh-theme file: https://github.com/KrystianDerdzinski/zshPower10kCustomConfig/blob/master/.p10k.zsh

Full error message:

> Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An AppArmor policy
> prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient;
> type="method_call", sender=":1.16780" (uid=1000 pid=211442
> comm="dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlay"
> label="snap.code.code (complain)")
> interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="Get" error
> name="(unset)" requested_reply="0"
> destination="org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify" (uid=1000 pid=175059
> comm="/snap/spotify/56/usr/share/spotify/spotify "
> label="snap.spotify.spotify (enforce)")

After executing

```
sudo snap connect code:mpris spotify:spotify-mpris
```

I get the following error:

```
error: snap "code" has no plug named "mpris"
```

Anybody knows how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out - snaps apparmor profiles are stored in /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles, not in /etc/apparmor.d as regular applications.

I created a symlink between spotify profile and /etc/apparmor.d

```
sudo ln -s /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.spotify.spotify /etc/apparmor.d/
```

Then i set spotify apparmor profile to complain mode

```
sudo aa-complain snap.spotify.spotify
```